# What are the left and right zeroes of the binary union operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $S$ be a set with an operation $\circ$. An element $z$ of $S$ is called a left-zero if $z \circ s=z$ for every $s \in S$ and a right zero if $s\circ z=z$ for every $s\in S$.

Find the zeros of:

Let $S$ be set of all subsets of a set $U$. Then the rule, $x \circ y=x \cup y$ for each $x$ and each $y$ in $S$, describes an operation $\circ$ on $S$ since it assigns one and only one element of $S$ to each pair $(x,y)$ of $S\times S$.

Comment: What have you tried? (If you're not sure what to do, try playing with U = {a, b, c}, for example.)

Comment: There's no real need to introduce the new symbol $\circ$. You can just use the symbol $\cup$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $x = x \cup y$.

What does that tell you about the relationship between $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 0):

The only zero in this case is $U$.

**Proof**:  We have $z \cup x = z$ for all $x \in S = P(U)$.  In particular, $U =  z \cup U = z$

Comment: @RossMillikan I don't see a flaw in what I wrote.  Please point it out!

Comment: @RossMillikan You are confusing yourself!  The OP defined a (left) zero to be an element $z \in S$ such that $z \circ s = z$ for all $s \in Z$.  You are mistakenly treating the $s$ as a zero.